# Is it possible for a clause to be reduced when it uses the verb "to be"?

Tags: clauses, reduced-relative-clauses

Is it possible for a clause to be reduced when it uses the verb "to be"?
Here's an example sentence:

> When I'm lazy, I usually sleep.

Can I reduce the when clause here to:

> When being lazy, I usually sleep.

?

Comment: Yes, but why would you want to do that?

Comment: Because s|he's lazy, I suppose.

Comment: It could be reduced even more: *When lazy, I sleep.* (This is also a semantic reduction as the frequency adverb has been removed.)

Answer (score 1):

If the meaning is clear, we often leave out words in conversation. It's called **ellipsis**.

So, you can even omit "I'm" or "being' and say "When lazy, I usually sleep." Please note that the sentence is informal now, unlike "When I'm lazy, I usually sleep", which is neutral.

Comment: but omitting the conjunction changes the meaning to "I am habitually lazy ..."

Comment: @aml right... “being lazy” is not the same as “when lazy”. Not to confuse anyone here, I have edited my answer. Thank you for your comment.